# Redirect only stdout to pipe and stderr to /dev/null

Tags: shell, pipe, io-redirection

I have this snippets that checks for latency to a url.

```
latency=$(timeout 10 ping -4 -qc5 $url 2>&1 | awk -F/ '/^(rtt|round-trip)/ { printf "%.1f", $5 } END{ if(!NR) print "busy" }')
```

The problem is, when executed on alpine linux, it will throw `terminated` message had the timeout has passed. I have simulate this by putting very low duration for timeout.

```
$ timeout 1 ping -4 -c5 $url 2>&1 | awk -F/ '/^(rtt|round-trip)/ { printf "%.1f", $5 } END{ if(!NR) print "busy" }'
Terminated
```

But I just found out that redirecting stderr to `/dev/null` will suppress that message.

```
$ timeout 2 sleep 5 2>/dev/null
$
```

But when I put in on my original snippets, it still spouting `terminated` message.

```
$ timeout 1 ping -4 -c5 $url 2>/dev/null | awk -F/ '/^(rtt|round-trip)/ { printf "%.1f", $5 } END{ if(!NR) print "busy" }'
Terminated
```

Can anyone point out the mistake here ?

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting the stderr from the `timeout` command. Since redirection operators can appear anywhere in the command, your

```
timeout 1 ping -4 -c5 $url 2>/dev/null
```

is equivalent to

```
timeout  2>/dev/null 1 ping -4 -c5 $url
```

or

```
2>/dev/null timeout 1 ping -4 -c5 $url
```

Do instead a

```
timeout 1 bash -c "ping -4 -c5 '$url' 2>/dev/null"
```